# From unsupervised to supervised in fraud detection

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I have a question. I am working on the fraud detection domain. And I have data from imports to the country. As you can get from the title, I have unsupervised data. I do not know that the record is fraudulent. But I have domain knowledge of what fraudulent behaviour might have and (smuggling vs) I want to randomize some records and flag them as fraudulent behaviour (meaningful randomness not all the features). With this information, I want to train my neural network to distinguish fraudulent behaviours. The approach I have in mind so far:

1. Train, Test split
2. In train data, create fraud data with randomizing algorithm (das,
   Schneider 2007 APD)
3. Train Neural network on train data
4. In test data create fraud data with randomizing algorithm - this
   time with a different algorithm ( R. Triepels, H. Daniels, and A.
   Feelders, “Data-driven fraud detection in international shipping,”
   Expert Systems with Applications, vol. 99, pp. 193–202, 2018.)
5. test the model

I found some similar approaches (from unsupervised to supervised fraud detection, (Ghosh, Anup K., and Aaron Schwartzbard. "A Study in Using Neural Networks for Anomaly and Misuse Detection." USENIX security symposium. Vol. 99. 1999.) But I want to see more papers or a thesis on this topic. Does anyone have advice or comment on this topic